# Splash page for CakePHP which remembers where the user was going?

Tags: cakephp, redirect, splash-screen

I want to build a splash page for a CakePHP site which will show up if a user has not visited the site before (no session data?) but remember where they were going (get the URL) then when they carry on to the page they are set to the place they were going.

The site is a Japanese help site and has an embedded font which is about 5mb~ so I want to give the user the option to Download a local copy or (maybe) turn it off for that session.

Any suggestions for an optimal way to do this with CakePHP?

Comment: I guess you answered your question, SESSION and COOKIE is your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a copy of `lib/Cake/Controller/AppController.php` and put it on `/app/Controller/AppController.php` if you don't have one in there already. Override its parent's `beforeFilter()` method to something like this:

```
function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();

    // check for session
    if (!$this->Session->check('been_here')){
        // If the visitor hasn't been here before, tell your session object he has now.
        $this->Session->write('been_here', true);

        // Store current request URI in session and send him to the splash page
        $this->Session->write('redirect_url', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'pages', 'action' => 'splash'));
    }
}
```

Now on your `PagesController::splash()`, you should render your splash page, control the actions the visitor does, and then send them to whatever there is on `$this->Session->read('redirect_url');`. Remember to delete this data from the session with `$this->Session->delete('redirect_url')` before the redirection.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is not the most elegant way of writing the solution, but you can get the idea and refine it later.

Comment: Thanks luchomolina, I will give this a try.

Comment: Hint - if some answer is a solution - mark it by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late response, I had not had time to try your suggestion, I have now and have run into issues, could you clarify: Is there any value I should change in the example you gave or copy verbatim? (I left 'action' => 'splash' and made a function splash() in the controller then made a splash.ctp in views/pages but it wont load. (also I have only ever used the default.ctp for views which has the font so where would I tell it to use a different layout or wrap the css calls in an if(not splash) loop? sorry for the over detailed explanation request.

Comment: Yes, it should work as is but only to send people to the splash page if they haven't "been_here" before, so notice it will only happen once. So what's happening? Try to call /pages/splash directly and see what happens. You could also debug the code to see what's failing.

Comment: Regarding the css calls and layouts, that's a whole other issue. But the documentation is pretty clear about. Please check http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#layouts

Comment: Thanks, I got some more help, found out I needed to fix redirects and login authorisation for the splash page. still not working but I jest need to hack at the details now.